# MaterializeCSS - Content showing outside container

Tags: materialize, css-frameworks

I'm using MaterializeCSS for creating layouts, I've got a container which contains 2 rows but any content which is not in column displays outside of container.

Here is my code:-

```
<div class="container">
    <div style="border: 1px solid #b1b1b1;">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col s12">Hello</div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">World
            <div class="col s12">Hello</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is how it looks:-

[Container Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOgAS.png)

Why is this happening even though my content is inside container and should also display within container boundaries?

Edit:

```
<div class="add-arena grey lighten-3">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col s12 center deep-orange white-text">Add Arena</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="add-arena-image-holder col s4">
            <form action="#">
                <div class="file-field input-field col s11">
                    <div class="btn">
                        <span>File</span>
                        <input type="file">
                    </div>
                    <div class="file-path-wrapper">
                        <input class="file-path validate" type="text">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="add-arena-description col s8">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="input-field col s6">
                    <input placeholder="What will it be called?" id="first_name" type="text" class="validate">
                    <label for="first_name">Arena Name</label>
                </div>
                <div class="input-field col s6">
                    <input placeholder="Arena Number" id="first_name" type="text" class="validate">
                    <label for="first_name">Arena</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col s3 right">
                    <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn deep-orange"><i class="material-icons left">send</i>Add</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All content should be in the actual cols as the rows apply negative margins to stretch them to the full width. Always put the content in the col's.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EXZzVr

```
<div class="container">
    <div style="border: 1px solid #b1b1b1;">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col s12">Hello</div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col s12">Hello World</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What exactly do you want to achieve?

Take a look at following lines:

https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/blob/0e13b80f6bfee1700dd2c2aa49494a44c8a61acb/sass/components/_grid.scss#L17-L18

https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/blob/0e13b80f6bfee1700dd2c2aa49494a44c8a61acb/dist/css/materialize.css#L3367-L3368

Comment: I'm again facing the same issue, this time I've put all content inside rows and columns still the issue is there. I've added the code, please have a look.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, it looks good with an extra "right" on the send button. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MoVVva

Comment: Have a look at [this image](http://imgur.com/a/tbZEq), this is how it looks, notice the top "Add Arena" bar and the content below it. Both add arena row and content are in row and yet one is taking a bit more width.

Comment: Not reproducible on the codepen, at least I can not see this there. Please check if any other styles were added eg some padding or margin on rows that do not come from Materialize.

Comment: I've checked, there are no styles added.